# cellForRowAtIndexPath misbehaves when loading more than once

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have created an app with swiping gestures with following code. the gestures should work for particular rows only. Its working perfectly when it loads for first time. from the second time the gesture function is working for every rows.

My code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GoalDetailsCell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[GoalDetailsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GoalDetailsCell"];
}

NSMutableDictionary *cellData = [self.databaseCall transactionFromDatabase:indexPath.row goalId:self.goalId andStageId:self.stageId];

cell.goalDescription.text = self.goalName;
cell.actionGoalDescription.text = self.goalName;
cell.tipsDescription.text = [cellData objectForKey:@"tipsDescription"];
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellData objectForKey:@"categoryImage"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [cellData objectForKey:@"cardType"]);

if([[cellData objectForKey:@"cardType"] isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftMethod:)];
    swipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [cell.cardDetails addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
    [cell.tryThisButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tryThisButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightMethod:)];
    swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [cell.actionCardReminder addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
    [cell.previousButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previousButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    cell.tryThisButton.hidden = NO;
    [cell.tryThisButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trythis.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.actionCardType setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toconsider.jpg"]];
    cell.cardType.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toconsider.jpg"];
    cell.cardTypeImage.hidden = YES;
    cell.actionCardGoalName.text = self.goalName;
    cell.actionGoalsImage.image = cellImage;
    cell.actionCardReminder.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.datePicker.layer.borderWidth = 0.2;
    cell.datePicker.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
}
else{
    cell.tryThisButton.hidden = YES;
    cell.cardTypeImage.hidden = NO;
    cell.cardType.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goodtoknow.jpg"];
    cell.cardTypeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tips.jpg"];
}

NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[cellData objectForKey:@"actionLink"]];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
[str addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

[cell.reminderSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(customSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

cell.weburl.attributedText = str;
cell.goalName.text = self.goalName;
cell.goalsImage.image = cellImage;
cell.cardDetails.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);

// Configure the cell...
return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using two different classes for each cell type.

Comment: can u provide me some sample program

Comment: I put some code as an answer (since it is too long to post as a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're reusing your cells with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` for a quick fix, you could perhaps explicitly remove the gesture recognizers in your else statement, ex:

```
else {
    cell.tryThisButton.hidden = YES;
    cell.cardTypeImage.hidden = NO;
    cell.cardType.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goodtoknow.jpg"];
    cell.cardTypeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tips.jpg"];

    // To remove all swipe gestures:
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in cell.cardDetails.gestureRecognizers) {
        [cell.cardDetails removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in cell.actionCardReminder.gestureRecognizers) {
        [cell.actionCardReminder removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
}
```

I do however think there are better ways to structure your code because you're also essentially layering gesture recognizers one on top of another as you reuse your cells. I think you need to figure out a way reuse your gesture recognizers like you're reusing your other outlets. But for a quick fix, my solution should work.

Comment: it shows the following error -[UIView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aff2f60

Comment: @Balaji Sorry about that. I left out ".gestureRecognizers" at the end of the loop lines. Should work now.

Comment: @Balaji What are cardDetails and actionCardReminder? UIViews?

Comment: @Balaji Actually shoot. I made one more mistake. Will update now.

Comment: cardDetails and actionCardDetails are the uiViews in a table cell.. Actually the error has gone but the behaviour is same as in the question.

Comment: @Balaji How about now

Comment: @Balaji Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter @ Lyndsey360

Comment: I have one more doubt in my previous application i have used navigation title its appeared as white in color but in application itsblack i dont know why.. codings are same..

Comment: @Balaji You should ask that in a separate question

Comment: @Balaji No. If you post your question on Stack overflow though today I'll probably see it.

Comment: pls look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191994/navigation-bar-title-color-looks-different-from-app-to-app-in-ios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653106/frame-is-not-changing-in-cellforrowatindexpath, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636660/frame-of-view-inside-the-cell-not-changing-in-cellforrowatindexpath, Can u please answer the above questions? Because u have helped me in this app before.

Answer (score 0):

You marked an answer already, but still here's some code:

In your viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[GoalDetailsTableViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GoalDetailsCell"];
[self.tableView registerClass:[GoalDetailsTableViewCellWithGestures class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GoalDetailsCellWithGestures”];
```

and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if([[cellData objectForKey:@"cardType"] isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
GoalDetailsTableViewCellWithGestures *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GoalDetailsCellWithGestures"];
// configure this type of cell (text, gestures, etc)
return cell;
}
else
{
GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GoalDetailsTableViewCell"];
// configure this type of cell (text, etc)
return cell;
}
```

Comment: But i didn't have any cell with identifier as "GoalDetailsCellWithGestures"

Comment: That's the idea: you create two different types of cells (one with gestures and another without gestures) and configure them accordingly.