# Navigation bar title color looks different from app to app in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have created two app. In both the apps I have used the navigation Controller and have used the same code. But in first app the navigation bar title appears as white but in second its black.. Can anyone help me to solve this.

I didnt use any code for separately for navigation bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the background color of navigation bar on both apps?

Comment: Its custom color partially green.

Comment: Check barStyle property of navigation bar.

Comment: where to see it.. It simply shows the Title, prompt and back button

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barStyle

Comment: If they're customized even slightly differently that could explain the difference.

Comment: @Lyndsey - i did not customize anything.. both apps are same

Comment: @Balaji You just said "Its custom color partially green"

Comment: @lyndsey. In first app also its same colour partially green